# focus after show doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, show

I have an input field in a text box as follows:

```
<div id="box_password2" style="display:none;">
  <span style="float:left;margin: 10px 0px 0px 20px;">Verify password:</span>                           
  <input type="password" id="field_password2" class="auto" maxlength="10" style="margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px; width: 80px; float: left;" value="">
</div>
```

I wish to unhide the box (and contained input field) and set focus to the input field as follows:

```
$('#box_password2').fadeIn("fast", function() {
  $("#field_password2").focus(); 
  console.log('Active element: '+$(":focus").attr('id'));
});
```

But this just doesn't work.  Focus is somewhere non-visible, and my console shows the active element as undefined.  Why isn't this working?

---

**UPDATE**

I added an onfocus alert and field_password2 DOES get focus, but somehow loses it to the NEXT field.  If it matters, the javascript above is in an onchange event for another input field.  Could it be that the onchange handler is changing focus AFTER my code changes focus?  Any way to prevent that?

Comment: Is `$("#field_password2")` displayed or hidden?

Comment: Works for me (Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/HYWjR/

Comment: Works for me in Safari

Comment: Wow. I've tried all the standard fixes--settimeout, trigger, return false--and nothing is working. http://jsfiddle.net/HYWjR/3/

Comment: It's working on chrome, but not on Firefox. You should always specify the browser that would help a lot.